# How to make a security form?

Tags: vb.net

I need help on how to do an authenticating password before adding a new user on my system... 
I'd used table name as `user_data` with ffg. columns `Username` and `Password`

Username is set to Admin and  the  way on how to login is setting only the password of Admin in correct  way.

This is my newbie code and i don't know how to do the query on it ...

```
    Try
        ConStr.Open()
        Dim User_Query As String
        User_Query = ""
        Cmd = New MySqlCommand(User_Query, ConStr)
        Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader


        frmAdduser.Show()

        Me.Hide()


        ConStr.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Access Denied!")

    Finally
        ConStr.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Please let me know your other ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You could retrieve the Admin password from the database, then compare it to what your user submitted. That might look something like,

```
User_Query = "SELECT Password FROM user_data WHERE Username='Admin'"
Cmd = New MySqlCommand(User_Query, ConStr)
Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteScalar

If (UserSubmittedPassword = Rdr) Then
    'allow access
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Access Denied!")
End If
```

Or, you could ask your database server to do the comparison for you.

```
User_Query = "SELECT CASE (SELECT Password FROM user_data WHERE Username='Admin') WHEN 'dataEnteredByUser' THEN True Else False END FROM user_data"
Cmd = New MySqlCommand(User_Query, ConStr)
Rdr = Comd.ExecuteScalar()

If (Rdr) Then
    'allow access
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Access Denied!")
End If
```